# Riggid Body Keyframed

Tags: rigging, rigid-body-simulation

I have a problem. I´m working in blender 2.9.3 i think... And i want that my tesla cybertruck, wich is keyframed, rams my mathe Teacher because he is stupid. But the Tesla doesn´t have any Physiks(It´s on passive) He drives trough everything(even an UV Sperhe on active)
So do you have some answers? I´m new in Blender(a few days) Doesn´t know how to do it.
(Sorry for my englisch... I´m from Germany and I´m an student...)

Comment: hello, could you please share your file (at least 2 objects that don't work, one active, one passive): https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: year wait a sec

Comment: i did it now but where is it now

Comment: read the instructions then share the link it gives you

Comment: its don´t do it. its a 2 Gb file

Comment: only keep few elements, or maybe try https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: here the file https://easyupload.io/oa3qmx

Comment: could you please only keep the useful object in your scene? i.e. the car and the object it hits. Plus I'm not sure why you created so many differente trees, it makes your scene much heavier, you could create just 3 trees and alt D to link-duplicate, but anyway if they are not useful for your problem, please delete them. Thanks

Comment: @moonboots thank you for helping. i fixed it now :) sorry that i stole your time

Comment: oh ok, great, so what was your problem?

Comment: i must make a tick for animation in rigid body setting at the tesla.